# Django ForeignKey attribute is not showing up in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have some models and connected each other. And in my views I get the *Chapter* model ordered by date published, and then remove the ones with same *Manga* (foreign key associated with other model).

But apparently accept for the fields is not connected with anything, and I can't access the models fields. But also because I am working with a query set I can't sort by id or anything. Also, I have to access the *Manga* models fields associated with chapter. But it does not show up in the HTML. How can I do it?

My models:

```
 class Manga(models.Model):
    manga_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="null")
    manga_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnail", default="thumbnail/noimage.png")
    manga_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}, {self.manga_name}"


class Fansub(models.Model):
    fansub_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="null")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}, {self.fansub_name}"

class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    chapter_url = models.URLField(default="www.example.com")
    manga = models.ForeignKey(Manga, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fansub = models.ForeignKey(Fansub, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.chapter_number}, {self.manga}, {self.fansub}"
```

My view:

```
def Index(request):
manga = Manga.objects.all()
chapter = Chapter.objects.all().values()
fansub = Fansub.objects.all().values()

mostview = manga.order_by("-manga_views")[:5]

relasedateorder = chapter.order_by("relase_date")

context = {
    "Manga": manga,
    "Chapter": chapter,
    "Fansub": fansub,
    "Mostview": mostview,
    "LastUpdated": relasedateorder,
}

template = loader.get_template("Index.html")
```

And finally the HTML:

```
{%for d in LastUpdated%}
    <p>{{d.manga}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: What is the actual indentation near "`def Index(request):`"? As posted, it is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the all the instances of `Manga` model associated with `chapter` instance by using `_set` as suffix in the following way:

```html
{% for i in LastUpdated %}
    <p>{{i.chapter_number}}</p>
    <h2> manga model attributes below</h2>
    {% for j in i.manga_set.all %}
        {{j.manga_name}}
        {{j.manga_views}}
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Also you should use `Chapter.objects.all().order_by("relase_date")` this queryset as using `.values()` gives you a key-value pair (dict).